# Even after giving vertical contraints the individual views are overlapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints

I am actually trying to have  UIView which houses UIImageView and UILabel (side by side). There are multiple such pairs present. I need these pairs one below the other. But after the second pair, the overlapping starts in spite of giving vertical contraints. The code below is actually resulting in Views getting overlapped (third and fourth getting on to second) I am unable to know exactly what is going wrong. Appreciate if somebody could point out this

```
    UIView *bottomCaseStudiesLyt = [[UIView alloc]init];
bottomCaseStudiesLyt.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = NO;
[contentView addSubview:bottomCaseStudiesLyt];

NSLayoutConstraint* bottomCaseStudiesleftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:bottomCaseStudiesLyt attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:10.0f];
[contentView addConstraint:bottomCaseStudiesleftConstraint];

NSLayoutConstraint* bottomCaseStudiesTopConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:bottomCaseStudiesLyt attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:details3View attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:10.0f];
[contentView addConstraint:bottomCaseStudiesTopConstraint];

NSLayoutConstraint* bottomCaseStudiesRightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:bottomCaseStudiesLyt attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:-10.0f];
[contentView addConstraint:bottomCaseStudiesRightConstraint];

NSLayoutConstraint* bottomCaseStudiesBottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:bottomCaseStudiesLyt attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
[contentView addConstraint:bottomCaseStudiesBottomConstraint];

//NSArray  *bottomCaseStudiesVConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[headingDetailsView]-[details2View]-[details3View]-[bottomCaseStudiesLyt]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"headingDetailsView": headingDetailsView,@"details2View": details2View,@"details3View": details3View,@"bottomCaseStudiesLyt": bottomCaseStudiesLyt}];

//[contentView addConstraints:bottomCaseStudiesVConstraints];

UIView *firstView = [[UIView alloc]init];
[firstView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[bottomCaseStudiesLyt addSubview: firstView];

[self addImageAndDetails:bottomCaseStudiesLyt previousview:nil whichimage:@"ic_action_easy" whattext:@"Rediculously easy. Takes less than 30 seconds to build a room and go live" mynewview:firstView];

UIView *secondView = [[UIView alloc]init];
[secondView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[bottomCaseStudiesLyt addSubview: secondView];

[self addImageAndDetails:bottomCaseStudiesLyt previousview:firstView whichimage:@"ic_action_amaze" whattext:@"Engage members with great content, services, offers, polls, notification, quiz and more" mynewview:secondView];

UIView *thirdView = [[UIView alloc]init];
[thirdView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[bottomCaseStudiesLyt addSubview: thirdView];

    [self addImageAndDetails:bottomCaseStudiesLyt previousview:secondView whichimage:@"ic_action_subscribers" whattext:@"Members ? No limit! There is a room for all. Go ahead and promote your room." mynewview:thirdView];

UIView *fourthView = [[UIView alloc]init];
[fourthView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[bottomCaseStudiesLyt addSubview: fourthView];

    [self addImageAndDetails:bottomCaseStudiesLyt previousview:thirdView whichimage:@"ic_action_crossplatform" whattext:@"Your room can be accessed from any platform or device." mynewview:fourthView];

   NSArray  *bottomViewVConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[firsView]-[secondView]-[thirdView]-[fourthView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"firsView": firstView,@"secondView": secondView,@"thirdView": thirdView,@"fourthView": fourthView}];
[bottomCaseStudiesLyt addConstraints:bottomViewVConstraints];

// GetStarted button
self->m_ObjGetStartedBut = [[UIButton alloc]init];

[self->m_ObjGetStartedBut setTitle: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Get Started"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self->m_ObjGetStartedBut.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self->m_ObjGetStartedBut setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self->m_ObjGetStartedBut.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
self->m_ObjGetStartedBut.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
self->m_ObjGetStartedBut.clipsToBounds = YES;
[parentView addSubview:self->m_ObjGetStartedBut];

NSDictionary *myTopViews = @{
                             @"scrollView": self->myScrollView,
                             @"submitButton": self->m_ObjGetStartedBut
                             };

NSArray *myTopVConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollView]-[submitButton(40)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:myTopViews];
NSArray *myTopHConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[submitButton]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"submitButton": self->m_ObjGetStartedBut}];


[parentView addConstraints:myTopVConstraints];
[parentView addConstraints:myTopHConstraints];

//[self->m_ObjGetStartedBut addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonIsReleased:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
//[self->m_ObjGetStartedBut setTag:1];
    }

    -(UIView *)addImageAndDetails:(UIView *)localparentView previousview:(UIView *)prevView whichimage:(NSString *)imageName whattext:(NSString *)relatedText mynewview:(UIView *)itemView
    {


NSLayoutConstraint* topViewleftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:itemView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:localparentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:10.0f];
[localparentView addConstraint:topViewleftConstraint];


NSLayoutConstraint* topViewRightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:itemView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:localparentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:-10.0f];
[localparentView addConstraint:topViewRightConstraint];

NSLayoutConstraint* topViewTopConstraint = nil;
if(prevView == nil)
{
    topViewTopConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:itemView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:localparentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
    [localparentView addConstraint:topViewTopConstraint];
}
else
{


   //topViewTopConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:itemView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:prevView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
    //[localparentView addConstraint:topViewTopConstraint];

}





UIImage *easyToCreateImg = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
UIImageView *easyToCreateImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:easyToCreateImg];

easyToCreateImgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
easyToCreateImgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = NO;
easyToCreateImgView.clipsToBounds = YES;
[itemView addSubview:easyToCreateImgView];

NSLayoutConstraint* easyToCreateImgLeftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:easyToCreateImgView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:itemView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:2.0f];
[itemView addConstraint:easyToCreateImgLeftConstraint];

NSLayoutConstraint* easyToCreateImgTopConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:easyToCreateImgView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:itemView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:2.0f];
[itemView addConstraint:easyToCreateImgTopConstraint];

NSLayoutConstraint *easyToCreateImgHtConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:easyToCreateImgView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:80.0f];
[itemView addConstraint:easyToCreateImgHtConstraint];

NSLayoutConstraint *easyToCreateImgWidConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:easyToCreateImgView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:80.0f];
[itemView addConstraint:easyToCreateImgWidConstraint];

UILabel* easyToCreateLblView = [[UILabel alloc]init];
[easyToCreateLblView setText:relatedText];
easyToCreateLblView.numberOfLines = 0;
UIFont *newHeadingViewLblFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];
[easyToCreateLblView setFont:newHeadingViewLblFont];
[easyToCreateLblView setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
easyToCreateLblView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[itemView addSubview:easyToCreateLblView];

NSLayoutConstraint* easyToCreateLblTopConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:easyToCreateLblView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterYWithinMargins relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:easyToCreateImgView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0f constant:2.0f];
[itemView addConstraint:easyToCreateLblTopConstraint];

NSLayoutConstraint* easyToCreateLblLeftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:easyToCreateLblView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:easyToCreateImgView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0f constant:2.0f];
 [itemView addConstraint:easyToCreateLblLeftConstraint];

NSLayoutConstraint* easyToCreateLblRightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:easyToCreateLblView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:itemView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:-10.0f];
[itemView addConstraint:easyToCreateLblRightConstraint];

return itemView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if my interpretation is right or wrong. What I observed is that when we give width and height constraints to the first view, this I think is not respected by the subsequent views that have been added. However, it does seem to respect the other constraints (top, bottom, leading, trailing). So when I started giving the same magnitude of width and height to the other subsequent views, then the arrangement came out as expected. Thoughts from the community are welcome.